# Basic GET Request using Express.js & Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, get, mocha.js

I'm working on an assignment to list all of the data in a mongoDB database, and am having trouble finding where I'm going wrong. It seems like a fairly simple problem, but whenever I run the provided mocha test, it keeps throwing 404 errors. Here is the relevant portion of the test:

```
  it('should it able to retrieve all listings', function(done) {
    agent.get('/api/listings')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        should.not.exist(err);
        should.exist(res);
        res.body.should.have.length(147);
        done();
      });
  });
```

And here is my code for the GET request. I've tried a few different ways of coding it, but this is seems like the simplest/most direct way to return the desired data as JSON.

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Listing.find(function(err, listing){
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send(err);
    } else {
    res.json(listing);
  }})
};
```

Is there anything else I should be doing? I've been looking at tutorials and basic examples of requests and it seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the middleware function (the code for GET request) is mapped to `/api/listings`
- I'm not sure about `exports.list`. It should probably be `module.exports`
- I'm assuming, based on ur code, that ur using the mongoose ODM. In which case, I think you need to pass a query to the find method [check this out](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)
- You might wanna make sure that you're connected to the database at the time of test initialization and that that completes before the test starts
- It always helps to log errors

Checkout [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to scaffold a boilerplate express app. Might help to compare it with your app, to check if it's wired correctly

Comment: I changed exports to module.exports, and updated the query to pass an empty object, which should return all available data. The GET request mapping would be in routes, right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not passing the first parameter to the [find method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find). Only the callback ... try this:

```
Listing.find({}, function(err, listing) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  } else {
    res.json(listing);
  }
})
```

I am assuming you want all records which is why we pass an empty object **{}**.